# CSS display issues in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

When we load this page in Chrome (https://www.prikkabelled.nl/product/2w-warm-witte-lampen/), everything looks fine:

But in Internet Explorer 11, we get a distorted display. Any idea what we can do to the CSS to look like it does in Chrome?

Perhaps some strange console errors are causing this?

Comment: I’d start by fixing the HTML. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.prikkabelled.nl%2Fproduct%2F2w-warm-witte-lampen%2F

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by applying CSS only applicable to IE 11:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none){
   // your CSS here for IE 11
}
```